# how to set HSTS header in create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, security, http-headers, create-react-app, react-helmet

I have an app I've been building and I started it with `create-react-app`. I am trying to make it more secure by adding HSTS headers or similar, but can't seem to find anything online that explains a way to do this when you haven't built your own custom server. Most answers are using nginx or apache. My backend is built in `node.js express` and uses `helmet.js` which is working fine, however my frontend is completely separate and I am guessing my backend being secure doesn't really solve the problem. I saw the `react-helmet` package but I'm not sure if this is what I'm looking for. Can you use that package to set this kind of http header and how would you do that?

Comment: I don't have much knowledge about  HSTS but doesn't this happen in the server? like in Apache instead of react?

Comment: @KuchBhi correct, headers such as HSTS are sent to the browser by the server. React doesn't have any control over it.

Answer (score -2):

Don't worry about security in the development mode build. You can't control hsts and other http headers sent to the browser by the server in development. You should worry about when hosting it for production. When you build it for production and serve it from your express server add this.

In your express server, you should be able to use the `hsts` middleman. So, if you just want hsts do this:

Run `npm install hsts`

and then add this to your express server.

```
const hsts = require('hsts')

app.use(hsts({
  maxAge: 15552000  // 180 days in seconds
}))
```

Or, you could use `helmet` which includes several other middlemen to increase security.

`npm install --save helmet`

```
var helmet = require('helmet')
app.use(helmet())
```

See [Best Security Practices on expressjs.com](https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-security.html)